# Exclusão de registro no BD MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde.
Preciso de uma ajuda em relação a exclusão de um registro do BD MySql.

Tenho um BD que tem uma tabela chamada CHAVES.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho uma página chamada listagem.php, essa página recebe os valores da tabela
CHAVES. Nessa página tem um link chamado EXCLUIR que ao clicar nesse link leva para uma página chamada exclusão.php.

Essa página exclusão uso $_GET para pegar o código correspondente no BD e preencher dinamicamente á pagina Exclusão.php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema:
Quando clicasse no botão confirmar a exclusão era para excluir o registro no BD e voltar para pagina Listagem.php com a página alteração atualizada sem a linha de registro.

Não estou conseguindo excluir o registro quando clico no botão está dando (erro na exclusão do registro).

Verifiquei o código várias vezes e não estou achando o erro que está impedindo a exclusão no BD e a atualização.

Ufa! é isso desculpem pelo longo texto, mas só assim acho que estou explicando meu problema.

Esse é o código: tive de colocar print do HTML do código porque está dando bug quando estou colando o código. Agradeço muito quem poder ajudar.

```
php
//confirmar se à página foi chamada a partir do formulário de exclusão
if(isset($_POST["nomecolaborador"])){
    $chID = $_POST["IDchaves"];

    $exclusao = "DELETE * FROM chaves ";
    $exclusao .= "WHERE IDchaves = {$chID} ";

    $con_exclusao = mysqli_query($conexao,$exclusao);
    if(!$con_exclusao){
        die("Erro na exclusão do registro");
    }else{
        header("location:listagem.php");
    }
}

?php
  //consulta a tabela chaves
  $cha = "SELECT * FROM chaves ";
  if(isset($_GET["codigo"]) ){
    $id = $_GET["codigo"];
    $cha .="WHERE IDchaves = {$id} ";
 }

  $cons_chaves = mysqli_query($conexao,$cha);
  if(!$cons_chaves){
      die("Erro na consulta");
  }
  $info_chaves = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cons_chaves);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retira o asterisco.

```
$exclusao = "DELETE FROM chaves ";
$exclusao .= "WHERE IDchaves = {$chID} ";
```

Vai dar certo!

Comment: Olá Júlio, cara o obrigado mesmo pela ajuda, ficamos tão cego olhando pra outro problema que a solução pode estar na nossa frente. Valeu mesmo!!

Comment: Há funcionou sua sugestão.

Comment: Infelizmente acontece isso, ficamos horas e horas procurando um problema complexo e depois descobrimos que é simples. :)

Comment: Super verdade, as vezes procuramos pelo em ovo. Forte abraço! :)